# FBX import: Broken material assignation

Tags: materials, export, import

I have a [3ds Max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_3ds_Max) scene with two objects with instanced geometry but different materials.

I exported the scene to FBX and imported FBX to Blender.

In Blender, both objects have the same material =(
(But I can see both materials as data-blocks.)

How can I save individual materials for these objects when I importing them to Blender?

Scene in 3ds Max (each object have individual material):

[Scene in 3ds Max http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20161124-w13n-144kb.jpg](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20161124-w13n-144kb.jpg)

Scene in Blender (both objects have the same material):

[Scene in Blender http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20161124-89eo-174kb.jpg](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20161124-89eo-174kb.jpg)